# ¿Como retornar la informacion de un select con mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, bootstrap, mongodb

he estado intentado realizar una app para el control de condominios, pero quiero que el usuario cuando notifique su pago, mediante un select, seleccionar con cual método de pago lo ha realizado con un custom-select, tengo 3 opciones Dólares, Pesos, Paypal, como hacer para que ese dato que si se guarda en la bd, me retorne por una modificación? el problema es que no me esta retornando lo que el guarda

he intentado con value="frmpago"

previamente declarado en el modelo, y en el crear

pero este no me devuelve nada de la BD, sin embargo para los inputs si me funcionan...

en el select tengo esto

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<label>Forma de pago</label>
<select class="custom-select" name="frmpago" value="{{propietario.frmpago}}">
<option selected >Seleccione...</option>
<option value="Pesos">Pesos</option>
<option value="Dolares">Dolares</option>
<option value="Zelle">Zelle</option>
<option value="Otro">Otro</option>
</select>
</div>
```

lo que tento en el controller

```
dashCtrl.proccessEditusuariosist = async (req, res) => {
const { cedula, name, apto, email, role } = req.body
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
cedula,
name,
apto,
email,
role,
})
res.redirect("/dashboard/usersist/")
}
```

y lo que tengo en modelo

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose")
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")
const PropietarioSchema = new Schema(
 {
cedula: {
type: Number,
name: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
apto: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
frmpago: {
type: String,
},
email: {
type: String,
required: true,
unique: true,
},
role: {
type: String,
},
password: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
},
)
```

Comment: Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: En la modificación, ese select de opciones de pago, debería poder cambiarse? Porque si no, cambia el select por un input y traes el texto como tal de la BD, sin necesidad de desplegar el select nuevamente. Otra opción sería cambiar el valor de option y agregar "selected" según el valor traído de la BD `<option selected >Valor original de la DB.</option>`

Comment: si ese campo tiene que seleccionarse o cambiarse, lo cambiaria el usuario, pero no consigo la forma que lo que agregue se quede cuando se edite sale Seleccione, no me trae el dato de la BD